# android- using nested alert dialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i m developing an app in which i m using *facebook login*
when the user clicks on a button .. i show an alert dialog whether the user wants to add the page to favorites...
 and if yes... then another alert dialog whether he wants to proceed using facebook login...
                                                                                               my question is
can i use nested dialogs,? or is there any other neater and cleaner solution to this?
suggestions welcome

thanks

Comment: may be you are repeating the following question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415478/android-nested-alertdialog-is-this-possible

Comment: i did see that, but that is not relevant to my query here

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested dialogs. You can call a dialog from another dialog. Add listeners to your first dialog buttons and in those listeners, dismiss the first dialog and starts the other one. What's the problem in doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the second dialog from the `onClick` handler of the 1st `AlertDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say Facebook Login do you mean the facebook android sdk? Also using less hacks is always good especially for UX. I wouldn't use nested dialogs also if you are using the facebook sdk then it actually loads up a separate activity. I would focus on making the app feel natural and not try any fancy hacks. This is something a lot of android developers forget to do which can be super frustrating to see.

Anyways i suggest you change the method by which people add the page to favorites. maybe use the menu button with menu, or maybe have a button or checkbox on the page not requiring any dialog.

Comment: thanks, yes m using the facebook android sdk, also the facebook login webview has a close button, so u think that would suffice?

Comment: i dont think so since some users will have the native app handle the click and others will have a webview so make sure that the native app can be handled in the same manner.

Comment: i used the force_auth parameter in authorize function so that webview wil always show up