# Show 2 alert dialog in the same actvity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Hi i am trying to set 2 alert dialog, 1 after the other,but it crash and i dont know how to solve it, the first one its showed but when i click on "ok" it stop (it doesnt crash with the red error but it stop working)

if someone can figure out where is the problem it will save me there is the code

```
    AlertDialog dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                 .setTitle("Introduce un nombre")
                 .setMessage("Esta es la primera vez que subes una foto, introduce un nombre que aparecera en tu foto")
                 .setView(input)
                 .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                         String nombre = String.valueOf(input.getText());
                        if(nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx,"¡Tu nombre no puede estar en blanco!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //entra =1;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            editor.putString("nombre",nombre);
                            editor.commit();
                            //entra = 0;
                             AlertDialog dialogo3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                             .setTitle("Introduce un nombre")
                             .setMessage("Esta es la primera vez que subes una foto, introduce un nombre que aparecera en tu foto")
                             .setView(input)
                             .setPositiveButton("Hombre", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                                 {

                                        editor.putString("genero","Hombre");
                                        editor.commit();


                                        GestorSubirFotos gestor = new GestorSubirFotos(ctx,prefs);
                                        String elnombre = prefs.getString("nombre", "");
                                        gestor.execute(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage),id,elnombre,phoneid);

                                 }
                             }).setNegativeButton("Mujer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                                        editor.putString("genero","Mujer");
                                        editor.commit();


                                        GestorSubirFotos gestor = new GestorSubirFotos(ctx,prefs);
                                        String elnombre = prefs.getString("nombre", "");
                                        gestor.execute(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage),id,elnombre,phoneid);
                                 }
                             }).show();
                        }

                     }
                 }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                     //entra =1;
                     }
                 }).show();
```

i also tryed that way, but it doesnt work either

```
     final Builder dialogo3 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx)
                 .setTitle("Introduce un nombre")
                 .setMessage("Esta es la primera vez que subes una foto, introduce un nombre que aparecera en tu foto")
                 .setView(input)
                 .setPositiveButton("Hombre", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
                     {

                            editor.putString("genero","Hombre");
                            editor.commit();


                            GestorSubirFotos gestor = new GestorSubirFotos(ctx,prefs);
                            String elnombre = prefs.getString("nombre", "");
                            gestor.execute(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage),id,elnombre,phoneid);

                     }
                 }).setNegativeButton("Mujer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            editor.putString("genero","Mujer");
                            editor.commit();


                            GestorSubirFotos gestor = new GestorSubirFotos(ctx,prefs);
                            String elnombre = prefs.getString("nombre", "");
                            gestor.execute(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage),id,elnombre,phoneid);
                     }
                 });
                  Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                 .setTitle("Introduce un nombre")
                 .setMessage("Esta es la primera vez que subes una foto, introduce un nombre que aparecera en tu foto")
                 .setView(input)
                 .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                         String nombre = String.valueOf(input.getText());
                        if(nombre.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(ctx,"¡Tu nombre no puede estar en blanco!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //entra =1;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            editor.putString("nombre",nombre);
                            editor.commit();
                            //entra = 0;

                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    dialogo3.show();
                                }
                            }, 2000);

                        }

                     }
                 }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                     //entra =1;
                     }
                 });

                  dialogo.show();
```

Comment: please put entire code.

Comment: Think you can't use show() for multiple times for the same AlertDialog instance at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, now it should work--->

```
 DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do something
        }
 };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Do you really want to unjoin this event?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();
```

Comment: i tryied it and still the same erro :S

Comment: hi with this code when i put on the metoh onclick dialogo3.show(); it crash, so still not working :S

Comment: go through this link-->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415478/android-nested-alertdialog-is-this-possible

Answer (score 1):

You are missing calling `.create()` before calling `.show()` for the `Builder` to create the Dialog.

Comment: i dont think this is the issue because the first one is showed( in the end i made it) but when i click on "ok" it stop showing file editor instead of the red error of source