# how to open custom dialog box in a custom dialog box in android

Tags: android, dialog

my app contains a custom dialog box on button click in which i have some check boxes on selecting one of this check box it show me another dialog box with 3 check boxes plz help me 
 here is my code for opening first dialog box

```
ImageView img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image_menu);
        img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {

                // custom dialog
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu);

                Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btncross);
                // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                 dialog.show();
                 Spinner spin = (Spinner)dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinState);
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_state = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, states);
                 adapter_state.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 spin.setAdapter(adapter_state);
                 spin.setSelection(pos);
                 spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);



                 Button btnShare = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
                 btnShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
                        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        String shareBody = "Dry Day App ";
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "DryDayApp");
                        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
                        dialog.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

                    }

                 });


                 cb1 = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxHR);
                 cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener1);

                 cb2 = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDay);
                 cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener2);

                 cb3 = (CheckBox)dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                 cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener3);

                 preferences = getSharedPreferences("syllabus", 0);
                 cb1.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("c1" ,false));
                 cb2.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("c2" ,false));
                 cb3.setChecked(preferences.getBoolean("c3" ,false));


              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [Android nested AlertDialog - is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4415478/android-nested-alertdialog-is-this-possible)

Just Design a new xml layout as your dialog and create a new activity and set it's theme to   `@android:style/Theme.Dialog` in the manifest file under the activity tag ex:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="LocationDialog"> </activity>
```

in the Dialog click listener code start the activity as

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityMain.this).setMessage(
  "Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
             Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
      }
```

This will start your **new activity** as a dialog where you can apply your action easily.

**//EDIT**
You should read [Android display another dialog from a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662538/android-display-another-dialog-from-a-dialog) and [AlertDialog inside alertdialog android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579963/alertdialog-inside-alertdialog-android)